# Is there any way to list classes, fields, and functions, in C/CPP files using vim, ccls, and coc.nvim like vscode?

Tags: vimrc, vscode

I'm using `vim8.1 + coc.nvim + ccls` to work on C/CPP projects since my vscode always crashes. Many of the features on vscode can be implemented by several plugins. However, I have not found a plugin to implement such a feature shown in the image:
[image: This window allows me to quick browse all the classes, fields and functions on the .h/.cpp file]
In vscode this window allows me to quickly browse all the classes, fields and functions on the `.h`/`.cpp` file. In vim, an alternative solution is [Cross reference extensions](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/coc.nvim#cross-reference-extensions), but it lacks the information of classes in a file, and static members in a class.

I think the feature is important for code viewer. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure if this is a supported LSP feature, but if it is you would need to figure out what feature it is and how to trigger it. Otherwise, there are various plugins that might get close (_e.g._ by using tags or other mechanisms to give this sort of "outline").

Comment: i am aware of a symbols outline plugin for neovim and its lsp, not sure about vim.